# Proof of (AUBUC)n(AUB`UC)n(AUC)`

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am studying discrete maths and was giving a question as homework to prove **(AUBUC)n(AU¬BUC)n¬(AUC)= 0** using set algebra. I have spent many hours figuring this one out.  I believe I go got the right answer using set algebra but the answer seems so long I was wondering if there was a quicker route to the answer.  I will post the Question and my answer, I would be extremely grateful if anyone would give their opinion on if this is the only way to solve the question or if there is a quicker way.  I have proven each line in my proof using truth tables so I'm pretty sure I have the right answer.
[Proof of (AUBUC)n(AUB`UC)n(AUC)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZSMG.png)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  First: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your mathematical formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is correct. But:

1. Please be careful with those parentheses! For example, on the very first line you immediately drop a set of parentheses you really should not. So, that should be:

$\color{red}(((A \cup B \cup C) \cap A) \cup ((A \cup B \cup C) \cap \overline{B}) \cup ((A \cup B \cup C) \cap C)\color{red}) \cap \overline{(A \cup C)}$

2. Yes, you could have done things a lot faster as follows:

$$(A \cup B \cup C) \cap (A \cup \overline{B} \cup C) \cap \overline{(A \cup C)}$$

$$\overset{Distribution}{=}$$

$$((A \cup C) \cup (B \cap \overline{B}))\cap \overline{(A \cup C)}$$

$$\overset{Complement}{=}$$

$$(A \cup C)\cap \overline{(A \cup C)}$$

$$\overset{Complement}{=}$$

$$\emptyset$$

Comment: Thank you for your Help, at least i know my proof is correct. I have tried to work out how you came to your answer but I'm afraid i can't figure it out.

Comment: @user729029 which step is confusing you?  The first, the second, or both?

Comment: the second step, i cant work out how how you distributed it to get (A∪C)∪(B∩¬B))

Comment: @user729029 OK, see the result as $X \cup (Y \cap Z)$ with $X =A \cup C$, $Y=B$ and $Z =\neg B$. If you distribute that you get $(X \cup Y ) \cap (X \cup Z)$

Comment: Thanks once again, I see it now.  I wish I had worked this out earlier but i couldn't see it no matter how long i stared at the set identities rule.  I worked for hours on my proof and yet it was this simple.  Can you tell me you get your symbols? is there a special app you use?

Comment: @user729029 And just to be clear| I went the 'other way around'.  Remember that Distribution is an equivalence, and so it goes both ways.  Going the other way doesn't feel like Distribution (more like Factoring, or Reverse Distribution), but it is still Distribution.

Comment: @user729029 You use Mathjax notation to typeset the symbols. Just google Mathjax tutorial

Comment: Yes i can see it now,  in my proof i did reverse the distribution on one line so i don't know how i couldn't see this,I think i was just looking to hard at it, couldn't see the wood through the trees as it were. thanks for your help.I'll check out Mathjax

Comment: @user729029 Yes, I noticed you did Reverse Distribution in your own proof :). Remember this pattern though:  $(A \cup B) \cap (A \cup \neg B) =A$ ... that's how I solved it so quickly.